# Include javascript file downloaded from npm to app.js

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Fairly new to node and npm. So I have a main javascript called app.js, as well as webpack set up nicely.

I have the following script inside app.js:

```
//require in jquery    
var $ = require('jquery');
//require a constructor function download from npm
var WheelIndicator = require('wheel-indicator');
```

But how to I load [mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin)

, a jquery javascript library into app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it's source code, just require the module and it looks like it will add the plugin to jquery.

```
require('jquery-touchswipe');
```

Comment: and since it is a jQuery plugin, this line is always after var $ = require('jquery') correct?

Comment: The source code requires jquery itself, but I'd put it there anyway just for clarity yes.